# Detecting frame start/end in D3D hook

Tags: c++, directx, hook, direct3d

My program hooks D3D EndScene to draw an overlay; however, one particular game appears to call BeginScene/EndScene twice per frame (on the same device) to render its UI. Is there a way to tell that this is happening? I imagine Present is also called twice, probably with a different render target, but I can't know what arguments will be passed to Present while inside an EndScene hook. As a result, my overlay is displayed twice. How do I avoid this problem, i.e. tell when a new frame is started?

Answer (score 0):

Just check+set a flag when you render in EndScene, if set then don't render your overlay again.

Reset this flag in Present (if the proper parameter are set).